# D3.js: Zooming the x-axis and data with mouse wheel scroll

Tags: javascript, graph, svg, d3.js, visualization

I searched for other relevant questions, but either by way of me being new to D3 or just rusty as a coder, I can not figure this out.

I've got a graph and I want to be able to zoom in by scrolling the mouse wheel only on the a-axis and the data. Right now, I have the whole graph zooming on the roll of the mouse wheel opposed to just the x-axis.

Edit: This is my end goal, but perhaps with zoom in/out limits (One thing at a time though): http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/#15

Looks like there is code from that example posted here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/zoom-pan/zoom-pan-transform.html

```
graph.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
```

I've dropped my code thus far here: http://jsfiddle.net/toddsherman/x3uWK/

Any insights or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Part of answer, in the jsfiddle given as reference in source, there is :

```
chart.select(".xaxis").call(xAxis);
chart.select(".yaxis").call(yAxis);
```

which refers to something that may be interesting to you :

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x);
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");
```

with x and y which seems to be scaling functions :

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, graph_width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, max_val])
    .range([graph_height, 0]);
```

Also, there is a different transformation in the zoom function :

```
chart.selectAll(".chart rect").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + ",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ", 1)");
```

The translate argument is only the X axis and a 0 value for the Y axis.
The scale argument ins only the X axis and a 1 value for the Y axis.

That said, i'm not really sure how to help more

Comment: This is constructive - I'm going to dig into this tonight and see what I come up with. Thanks for the input. I'll let you know what I figure out.

Comment: ok, no luck yet. I think that those things you referred to as scaling functions are just how the axis scale is set opposed to the way one actively scales an axis/data. Thanks.

Comment: How about the parameters of the transform attributes ?

Comment: yeah, I this the key may be to somehow declare _something_ that is independent from the actual graph that can be scaled. In examining the source of this example [link](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/#15) they have _svg_ and _rect_ declared and I only use _graph_ which leads me to believe  I need to somehow compartmentalize how I'm doing this in order to independently scale the x-axis. Thanks for engaging.