# How to redraw data after d3.js zoom

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add a zoom behavior to this [lines chart (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu95q/11/)

I created the behavior like this:

```
zoomed = ->
  svgContainer.select(".x.axis").call xAxis
  svgContainer.select(".y.axis").call yAxis
  svgContainer.select(".line.matched_peak").attr("d", msBars);

zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                 .x(xScale)
                 .y(yScale)
                 .scaleExtent([1, 10])
                 .on("zoom", zoomed)

svgContainer.call zoom
```

where the scaling functions are already defined.

So it redraws and rescales both axis alright, but how can the data (lines here) can be redrawn? I have tried to do it with the line.

```
      svgContainer.select(".line.matched_peak").attr("d", msBars);
```

(I see something like that [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878681/x-axis-zooming-with-d3-line-charts)) . In my case msBars is the part where I bind my data to lines and scale them. But I am not sure what it does, and it does not feel alright here.

So, how a function to redraw the data can be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You quite simply do the same thing you did to draw the data in the first place, minus the `.append()`. So in your case, that would be

```
svgContainer.selectAll("line.matched_peak")
    .attr("x1", (d) -> return xScale(d.m_mz) )
                    .attr("y1", h - padding)
                    .attr("x2", (d) -> return xScale(d.m_mz) )
                    .attr("y2", (d) -> return yScale(d.m_intensity) )
svgContainer.selectAll("text.matched_peak_label")
    .attr("x", (d) -> return xScale(d.m_mz) )
                       .attr("y", (d) -> return  yScale(d.m_intensity) )
```

I've also applied the classes you're selection is based on to the created elements so that the selection works. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu95q/12/).

Comment: That definitely put me on the right path, however do you know if there is a function to set the boundaries or limits of the zooming? Because I see now some lines go out of the x and y axis lines...

Comment: You can limit the scale/translation like in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520).

Comment: And also, for panning, I see I can pan the graph up so the y values go below 0... Is there a way to prevent that?